# Segue from PFLogInViewController

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to segue to another view controller after a successful login with PFLogInViewController(), using parse, and it won't work.  The code is posted below.  The PFLogInViewController just keeps popping up and dismissing over and over.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        var logInController = PFLogInViewController()
        logInController.fields = (PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword
            | PFLogInFields.LogInButton
            | PFLogInFields.SignUpButton
            | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten
            | PFLogInFields.DismissButton)


        logInController.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(logInController, animated: true, completion: nil)



        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground("tester1", password: "test123"){
            (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if user != nil {
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                self.presentViewController(picsViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are recreating it in your viewDidAppear.  When the previous view completes, is viewDidAppear being called?  You may want to move it to viewDidLoad which would only be called once.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:_username.text password:_password.text block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOURSEGUEIDENTIFIER" sender:self];

    }

    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Error" message:@"There was an error login you in. Please check username and password and try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

}];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if it will fix all the problems but a good place to start would be to add the

```
     super.viewDidAppear(animated)
```

this may stop it from opening and closing

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}
```

on top of all the code on that controller